# Android Studio GPU Monitoring Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, monitor

I'm using v2.3.1 of Android Studio. I have a Nexus 6P device running Android 7.1.2, and I've went to Settings -> Developer Options -> Profile GPU Rendering and turned on `adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo`. Pausing and unpausing GPU in the Monitors tab does nothing but show a timeline with no data. I have selected the correct device, and package in the Monitor dropdown. I've tried killing and restarting adb. I've tried restarting Android Studio, and my phone. I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working.